# How to set up sender informtion correctly of exchange address type

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-redemption, sender, msg

In some of the msg files the sender information got deleted accidentally. I want to restore the sender information back in msg file. I am using Redemption library to restore info.

The info is getting restored correctly. I have verified the info using MFCMAPI utility. [Click to see sender info with Mapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkLAV.jpg)

But when I open fixed msg with outlook, The sender's exchange canonical name is displayed with sender's display name in UI. e.g "John</O=Exchange/OU=ExchangeAdmin....>"  in good msg it only displays "John".
[Click to see UI display differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxRHu.jpg)

I am using folowing code to restore sender info.

```
        var PR_SENDER_ADDRTYPE_W = 0x0C1E001F;
        var PR_SENDER_NAME_W = 0x0C1A001F;
        var PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W = 0x0C1F001F;
        var PR_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS = 0x5D01001F;


        Redemption.RDOSession oRdoSession = null;
        RDOMail oRdoMail = null;
        SafeMailItem sfItem = null;
        

           oRdoSession = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession(); // session = New Redemption.RDOSession
            oRdoMail = oRdoSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile(sFilePath);

            sfItem = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_SafeMailItem(); // CreateObject("redemption.safemailitem")
            sfItem.Item = oRdoMail;
            bool f_Changed = false;
            var f_EntryID = oRdoSession.CreateOneOffEntryID(p_FromDisplayName, p_FromAddressType, p_FromEmailAddress, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            var ID = oRdoSession.GetAddressEntryFromID(f_EntryID);
            oRdoMail.Sender = ID;
            oRdoMail.SentOnBehalfOf = ID;

            //SetFieldValue is nothing but  sfItem.Fields[PR_SENDER_ADDRTYPE_W] = p_FromAddressType 
            SetFieldValue(sfItem, PR_SENDER_ADDRTYPE_W, "PR_SENDER_ADDRTYPE_W", p_FromAddressType, ref f_Changed);
            SetFieldValue(sfItem, PR_SENDER_NAME_W, "PR_SENDER_NAME_W", p_FromDisplayName, ref f_Changed);
            SetFieldValue(sfItem, PR_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS, "PR_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS", p_FromSmtpAddress, ref f_Changed);
            SetFieldValue(sfItem, PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W, "PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W", p_FromEmailAddress, ref f_Changed);

            oRdoMail.Save();
```

Can you please let me know what am I missing.

For mor properties of sent info please check the screenshot.[Click to see ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwR9e.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook actually displays the `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_xyz` properties.

There is absolutely no reason to create an instance of the `SafeMailItem` - just use the `RDOMail` object returned by `RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile`

What are the values of the `p_FromAddressType` and `p_FromEmailAddress` variables? If you know the SMTP address, simply pass it to `CreateOneOffEntryID`:

```
var f_EntryID = oRdoSession.CreateOneOffEntryID(p_FromDisplayName, "SMTP", p_FromSmtpAddress, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_xyz properties are also set properly as present in Original email, I am attaching image of it in question. I am passing EX as AddressType and /O=Exchange/OU=ExchangeAdmin.... as p_FromEmailAddress. I wanted to preserve canonical name in sender info as it was in original email. I do have smtp information, I am setting SMPT address property after setting Ex type sender address.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your suggestion. But the solution is not working for me. Is there any way that I can sent your msg files that I tried to fix and the original file so that you can have all info related to the issue.

Comment: Do **not** pas "EX" as the address type when calling CreateOneOffEntryID.It needs to be "SMTP" and the address must be an SMTP address, not EX.

Comment: How would I preserve the legacyExchangeDn address (/O=Exchange/OU=ExchangeAdmin....) in email properties?

Comment: You can preserve it if you set the sender / sent-representing entry id to that retrieved from the corresponding GAL object instead of using CreateOneOffEntryID (which is really for SMTP, FAX, MSN addresses)